# Collapse multiindex after pivot() in pandas pipe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Comming from R/dplyr, I'm used to the piping concept to chain transformation steps during data analysis and have taken this to pandas in a sometimes similar, sometimes better but also sometimes worse fashion (see [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-flawless-pipes-of-python-pandas-30f3ee4dffc2) for reference). This is an example of a worse situation.

I'm conducting an analysis of some objects and want to understand the behavior by some grouping variable and for steps further dwon the line (which are not relevant here), I have to have the calculated metrics per grouping in seperate columns. Hence, I'm chaining `agg()` with `pivot()` and end up with a multiindex, which I'd like to collapse or flatten.

What I do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "object" : [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2],
    "grouping" : ["A", "B", "A", "A","A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B"],
    "attribute" : [38, 36, 36, 26, 29, 23, 38, 15, 27, 30]
    })

res = (
    test_df
        # calculate the metris
        .groupby(["object", "grouping"])
        .agg(
            metric1 = ("attribute", "count"),
            metric2 = ("attribute", "sum"),
            metric3 = ("attribute", "mean") 
        )
        .reset_index()
        # rearrange values by columns
        .pivot(
            index = "object",
            columns = "grouping",
            values = ["metric1", "metric2", "metric3"]
        )
        # more steps to come that would be way simpler with collapsed index
)
print(res)
```

Resulting in:

```
         metric1      metric2           metric3           
grouping       A    B       A      B          A          B
object                                                    
1            3.0  NaN   103.0    NaN  34.333333        NaN
2            1.0  3.0    15.0  104.0  15.000000  34.666667
3            1.0  2.0    26.0   50.0  26.000000  25.000000
```

Expected Ouput **as result of a chaining / piping step**:

```
object  metric1_A  metric1_B  metric2_A  metric2_B  metric3_A  metric3_B                                                    
1             3.0        NaN      103.0        NaN  34.333333        NaN
2             1.0        3.0       15.0      104.0  15.000000  34.666667
3             1.0        2.0       26.0       50.0  26.000000  25.000000
```

There are stackoverflow-answers that would allow me to collapse the multiindex by breaking the pipe, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087020/collapse-a-pandas-multiindex) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns), but I'd like to sustain the pipe since the whole piping process supports the thought-process of data analysis so well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html)

We can flatten the columns without breaking the method chaining by using `pipe` method and passing in a lambda function that uses [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) along with [`MultiIndex.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) to flatten the columns:

You can chain the below `pipe` call after your `pivot` method

```
.pipe(lambda s: s.set_axis(s.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1))
```

---

```
        metric1_A  metric1_B  metric2_A  metric2_B  metric3_A  metric3_B
object                                                                  
1             3.0        NaN      103.0        NaN  34.333333        NaN
2             1.0        3.0       15.0      104.0  15.000000  34.666667
3             1.0        2.0       26.0       50.0  26.000000  25.000000
```

Comment: with another `.reset_index()` it becomes really flat but that was exactly what I was looking for!!!! Thank you so much. And during all my search, I've never found the `.pipe()` function.

Comment: @Racooneer Glad i could help!